# Device Detection from TCP traffic using Java

Tags: java, android, sockets, tcp

I have an android client and Java server, communicating with each other over TCP Sockets. I want to restrict the java server to accept traffic from mobile device only, but cant find a way to detect whether the traffic is from android or desktop. I have find other ways to detecting devices by getting header from HTTP requests, but how can I get any such information from TCP header or packet. Or is there any other way to restrict traffic from desktops?

Comment: By definition you can't do that; TCP is supposed to be medium independent, and with reason. Admittedly, there do exist packages which can guess what OS is on the other end (nmap, for instance) but that requires very deep packet inspection and in the end those are just heuristics. And inspection at that level is not readily available in Java, except if you use jpcap or equivalent. Anyway, why do you want to do that?

Comment: Thanks for the response. For the question why do I want to do that is 
I think that someone can just create a java client on desktop an flood my server causing the bandwidth and resources get choked at some level.

Comment: Bandwidth throttling should not be the concern of your application to begin with; tools exist which can alleviate such risks for you _before_ your application is even reached. Divide and conquer! But such risk alleviation _is not_ what your application itself should be concerned about.